# HTML table to database

Tags: python, c#, html, database, html-agility-pack

At this point, my table looks as follows:

```html
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="ms-formtable" id="formTbl" style="margin-top: 8px;" width="100%">
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td class="ms-formlabel" nowrap="true" valign="top" width="165px">
      <h3 class="ms-standardheader">
        <a name="SPBookmark_FileLeafRef">
        </a>
        Name
      </h3>
    </td>
    <td class="ms-formbody" id="SPFieldFile" valign="top" width="450px">
      <a href="http://google.com" onclick="DispDocItemEx(this, 'FALSE', 'FALSE', 'FALSE', '');">
        X
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="ms-formlabel" nowrap="true" valign="top" width="165px">
      <h3 class="ms-standardheader">
        <a name="SPBookmark_Owner">
        </a>
        Name@
      </h3>
    </td>
    <td class="ms-formbody" id="SPFieldChoice" valign="top" width="450px">
      Z
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="ms-formlabel" nowrap="true" valign="top" width="165px">
      <h3 class="ms-standardheader">
        <a name="SPBookmark_DirectiveRank">
        </a>
        Age
      </h3>
    </td>
    <td class="ms-formbody" id="SPFieldChoice" valign="top" width="450px">
      52
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="ms-formlabel" nowrap="true" valign="top" width="165px">
      <h3 class="ms-standardheader">
        <a name="SPBookmark_Number">
        </a>
        number
      </h3>
    </td>
    <td class="ms-formbody" id="SPFieldText" valign="top" width="450px">
      1
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="ms-formlabel" nowrap="true" valign="top" width="165px">
      <h3 class="ms-standardheader">
        <a name="SPBookmark_Title">
        </a>
        Name of File
      </h3>
    </td>
    <td class="ms-formbody" id="SPFieldText" valign="top" width="450px">
      Funny Names
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="ms-formlabel" nowrap="true" valign="top" width="165px">
      <h3 class="ms-standardheader">
        <a name="SPBookmark_EffectiveFrom">
        </a>
         date
      </h3>
    </td>
    <td class="ms-formbody" id="SPFieldDateTime" valign="top" width="450px">
      1.1.2022
    </td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[image: Table]

I basically need to open an HTML file, filter table with id "formTbl" and then either create JSON with values : `{Firsttd:Secondtd, "Name":"Test", "Date":"Blank"}` or insert into database where First td (in tr tag we have 2 td, first it name of column and second is value) in table A and second td in table B. Is there any way? I´ve tried using Python, where I got so far json looks like `[["","Name","","Test",""],["","Age","","12",""]]` and in C# I´ve tried HTMLAgilityPack but it wasn´t working.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution with JQuery.

```
<html>
    <body>
    
        <table id="example-table">
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Name@</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Number</th>
                <th>Name of file</th>
                <th>Date</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>X</td>
                <td>Z</td>
                <td>52</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Name of file</td>
                <td>2021-22-10</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    
        <textarea rows="10" cols="50" id="jsonTextArea">
            
        </textarea>
    
    </body>
    </html>
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/table-to-json@1.0.0/lib/jquery.tabletojson.min.js"></script>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
    
        var tableToJson = $('#example-table').tableToJSON();
    
        var sendingData = JSON.stringify (tableToJson);
    
        $('#jsonTextArea').val(sendingData);
    
    
    // Send JSON data to backend
    $.post('http://localhost/test.php', {sendingData}, function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
        var backendResponse = data;
        console.log(backendResponse);       
    });
    
    </script>
```

Comment: I need to upload like 3000 html pages and need to do it by adding link, something like this `for (int i = 0; i <3000; i++) {  send data from table into database}` every page has same table just with diff. values

Comment: And my table is as I mentioned in question (`<table> <tr> <td> Column</td <td> Value </td> </tr> ..... </table`>